# Getting divs to move from inline to stacked with media queries

Tags: css, html, media

I have 3 divs that I want to make responsive. For max-width 990px, I'd like to have them be a 3 column layout. For over max-width 650px, I'd like to have the first two divs span to 30%-70% to fill the whole length, and the 3rd column go underneath and span the whole length.

What I have so far works in Chrome but buggy in Firefox.

The key is that I can't have any white space between the divs at all.

```
    <div class="columns">
    <div class="left-nav-menu">Left Column</div>
    <div class="center-content-area">Center Column</div>
    <div class="right-column">Right Column</div>
    </div>

    @media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    div.columns {background-color:#360; display:table; width: 100%; padding: 0em;}

    div.left-nav-menu {width: 30%; margin: 0; padding: 2em; background-color: #CCC; 
    display:table-cell;}

    div.center-content-area {width: 40%; margin: 0; padding: 2em;
    background-color: #C9F; display: table-cell;}

    div.right-column {width: 30%; margin: 0; padding: 2em; background-color: #CCC;
    display: table-cell;}

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    div.columns {background-color:#360; display:table; width: 100%; padding: 0em;}

    div.left-nav-menu {width: 30%;margin: 0; padding: 2em; background-color: #CCC;       
    display: inline-table; }

    div.center-content-area {width: 70%; margin: 0; padding: 2em;
    background-color: #C9F; display: inline-table;}

    div.right-column {width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 2em; background-color: #CCC;
    display: block;}

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a fiddle using your code.
I've edited your HTML and CSS a little but it should work in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="box left">Left Column</div>
  <div class="box center">Center Column</div>
  <div class="box right">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4LYS/1/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! It seems I need to define "display" for the 990 left, right, and center classes. Is there value you'd recommend?

Comment: Also it seems I can't add padding or borders to these w/o breaking it. Any advice for getting text away from the edges?

Comment: It'll break because the padding is adding to the width.

I've changed the fiddle a little to add 2% padding - http://jsfiddle.net/j4LYS/7/